# Can I change size of fedex label pdf?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, pdf, fedex

I've created label using fedex API.

and I save that PDF Image into AWS. Below is url.

[https://s3-ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/gmp01/**temp**/tmp-137164OTxA4P5MVJ1.pdf](https://s3-ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/gmp01/__temp__/tmp-137164OTxA4P5MVJ1.pdf)

This label has 4X6 size. but you can see pdf size is A4 in that link.

I've tried to find How can I remove this white space but I can't find in Fedex API Document.

If you have had this similar issue, please help me.

I am using Angular.js 1.x and Node.js

Comment: The 4x6 is the standard FedEx pouch size. But, have you tried using `LabelSpecification/LabelStockType` property with value `PAPER_LETTER` to specify the `A4` output format? Or when using the WS methods use the `paper_size` parameter with value `a4`

Comment: @daan.desmedt https://s3-ap-northeast-2.amazonaws.com/gmp01/__temp__/tmp-113564JLoF3Rkr2tH.pdf This link is what I send with PAPER_LETTER, and I can't understand what you said. what is the WS methods? and where can I find paper_size parameter? Thanks your answer.

Comment: Can you provide me with more information on the Fedex API you are using? Link to ApiDOC version is enough. Seems there are some differences in versions....

Comment: http://www.fedex.com/templates/components/apps/wpor/secure/downloads/pdf/201408/ShipServiceWSDLGuide_v2014.pdf

and I send data like this.
"LabelSpecification": {
              "LabelFormatType": "COMMON2D",
              "ImageType": "PDF",
              "LabelStockType": "PAPER_LETTER"
            }

Comment: @daan.desmedt Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Try setting the `LabelStockType` to `PAPER_4X6`, since the label itself has size 4x6, change the paper format to the same size. So the printer can scale it if needed. In case this does not solve the problem, please contact FedEx WS team at http://www.fedex.com/us/web-services/support.html.

Answer (score 1):

We get the 4x6 PDF label for FedEx and trim the white space by getting the PNG file first. Below you can find the parameter.

- LabelFormatType = COMMON2D
- ImageType = PNG
- LabelStockType = PAPER_4X6

If you want to save time, you can use RESTful shipping API like [Postmen](https://docs.postmen.com/fedex.html) which simplifies the API request for label generation.